# Found weird behavior with Joda API

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I started looking at **joda** API for handling timezone related issues for my web application. I found very weird behavior while doing so. I hope there must be some workaround. here is my snap-code.

```
DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), currentDateTime.toLocalDateTime()).getSeconds();
System.out.println("hours::" + (((float)seconds)/(60*60)));
```

My local timezone is : **kolkata, India** (GMT + 5:30)
 then I should get **5.5** as myn console output, but I am getting **hours::5.499722** 
Don't know Why? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How is `hours`, an `int`, going to hold the non-integer value `5.5`? I'm not very familiar with joda, but it looks like you may want to get `Minutes.minutesBetween` and work with that, instead.

Comment: you are right.. see my edited question..still there is doubt.

Comment: Now you have floating point rounding errors. See http://floating-point-gui.de. It sounds like you want to work with (hours, minutes) as a pair, which Jon Skeet's answer shows how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(5.5 hours - 5.499722 hours) in ms
=
1000.8 ms
```

1 second, to the rounding/floating point precision. You call

```
DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
```

`Seconds.secondsBetween().getSeconds()` gives you an integer number of seconds. Your calls are successive meaning they can be off by even 1 millisecond, which can be rounded to 1 second when converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want hours and minutes (an `Hours` object can only hold an integer number of hours) you probably want:

```
Period period = new Period(utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), 
                           currentDateTime.toLocalDateTime(),
                           PeriodType.time());
```

Or alternatively, and more cleanly IMO:

```
int offsetMillis = DateTimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(Instant.now());
Duration offset = Duration.millis(offsetMillis);
```

You should very rarely need to know the offset in this fashion though, in my experience.